# Semantic UI Dropdown Testing

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am trying to test out the Semantic UI [Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) module from Semantic UI.

When I try to use it, it does not actually "drop down".  I have tried to figure it out, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ui multiple dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" name="filters">
      <i class="filter icon"></i>
      <span class="text">Filter Posts</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="ui icon search input">
          <i class="search icon"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search tags...">
        </div>
        <div class="scrolling menu">
          <div class="item" data-value="important">
            <div class="ui red empty circular label"></div>
            Important
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-value="enhancement">
            <div class="ui orange empty circular label"></div>
            Enhancement
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**What do I need to do to get Semantic UI Dropdown to work?**

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add a script to fire up semantic ui:

```
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
```